# How to do the same code for several checkboxes to set the checkbox Value?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have in my Excel userform several checkboxes (in total 10) which all should be have the same behavior. It means, when I reload the form the value of the checkbox should change, depending on values from the spreadsheet with the actual selected row.

The following code is working properly for one checkbox:

```
If Sheet1.Cells(iRow, Sheets("aux").Range("B21")) = "X" Then
    cbERW.Value = True
ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(iRow, Sheets("aux").Range("B21")) = "?" Then
    cbERW.Value = Null
Else
    cbERW.Value = False
End If
```

How can I do this in the easiest way for multiple checkboxes? But for every checkbox the referring row and column could change. For example, the next one look like this (`cbHSAW` instead of `cbERW`, Column `B22` instead of `B21`):

```
If Sheet1.Cells(iRow, Sheets("aux").Range("B22")) = "X" Then
    cbHSAW.Value = True
ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(iRow, Sheets("aux").Range("B22")) = "?" Then
    cbHSAW.Value = Null
Else
    cbHSAW.Value = False
End If
```

Anybody know how to do this easily?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your test statement in a function and pass the range for the specific checkbox. Then set the return result can be as the value for the checkbox. The below needs to be modified for your form and ranges but will give the desired result.

```
'Function to test the value of the range
Private Function SetCheckBox(ByVal rng As Range)
If rng.Value = "X" Then
    SetCheckBox = True
ElseIf rng.Value = "?" Then
    SetCheckBox = Null
Else
    SetCheckBox = False
End If
End Function


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Set value for each checkbox by passing its range to the function
CheckBox1.Value = SetCheckBox(Sheets("aux").Range("A1"))
CheckBox2.Value = SetCheckBox(Sheets("aux").Range("A2"))
CheckBox3.Value = SetCheckBox(Sheets("aux").Range("A3"))
CheckBox4.Value = SetCheckBox(Sheets("aux").Range("A4"))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your issue would you kindly mark it as the answer? Thank you